# Attempting to detect a string in c++

Tags: c++

I have some code for an assignment here.

```
stringstream fNameStream(fName);
    stringstream lNameStream(lName);
    if (fNameStream >> word)
    {
        fNameStream >> names[count];
        count++;
    } 
    else
    {
        fNameStream << "John";
        fNameStream >> names[count];
        count++;
    }
```

The error is I get no values at all when I check my array later. So I'm not sure what the issue is. When I entered in the values before without the if loop I was able to get values, but when I do it this way I get nothing.
Apologies if this is incoherent or not clear (just let me know) I'm quite hungover.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: maybe you should drink some tomato juice. :-D

Comment: lol, I'm working on it >_<. Its tough cause this is due at 12 tonight! Procrastination ftw

Comment: Crap, the if loop >_<

Comment: @harrisoncrazy A loop is something to repeat a code part. `if` is not a loop.

Comment: @harrisoncrazy - if you only want to make sure that fName only contains letters (as you state in a comment to the answer below) why use all the stringstream and array stuff. I think you need to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
bool isWord(std::string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i)
    {
        if (!::isalpha(s[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    while (fNameStream >> word)
    {
        if (isWord(word))
        {
            names[count++] = word;
        }
        else
        {
             // placeholder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is make an error checker, to make sure the thing I am entering is actually a string.

Comment: @harrisoncrazy what do you mean by 'string' do you mean contains only letters or non-numerical-digits?

Comment: Only letters, I need to detect if the name im looking for is actually a name and not numbers or symbols, and if it is switch it for a placeholder string

Comment: @harrisoncrazy Does this answer fix the specific problem you asked about?

Comment: No. What im trying to do is check if somthing is a string. I'm using the string word (which is empty) to check that the value for fName is in fact a string

Comment: I'd imagine it would,  but for whatever reason the open bracket isn't attached to the bool line, it says its expecting a ;

Comment: @harrisoncrazy, as posted it's not compilable. You need to adjust the code appropriately. The `isWord` function needs to go at global scope (same as `main`, for instance). The while loop you need to add where necessary.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, trying it now. Sorry, I'm still really new to c++

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz: I recommend you get in the habit of using the correct form of the `main` function, as it returns `int` always.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, ah well. I don't think it really matters when the return value means nothing. But I changed it to make you happy. :-P

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz - and don't forget to return something... ;-)

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz - lol... Just like all the undefined variables. Anyway - I'm quite impressed that you even hat a clue what the question is about. Though I still can't match your answer with the question and comments. :-)

Comment: Its worked! Thank you! Now just to do the same thing with the ints

Comment: @harrisoncrazy, Glad I could be of assistance. Good luck on your assignment and maybe drink something other than a depressant.